# a problem with wavread function

Tags: matlab

I wrote a program that record my voice write it and then play it

```
Fs=11025;
y= wavrecord(2*Fs,Fs,'int16');
wavwrite(y,Fs,'t1.wav');
wavplay(y);
```

I heard my voice clear 
then I want to write another program that reads that file and play it

```
y=wavread('t1.wav');
wavplay(y);
```

when I run the second program I didn't hear my voice clear

so how can I read the wav file and then play it without a problem?

Answer (score 1):

The `wavwrite` you used may assume that the incoming `y` is of range [-1 +1]. Try to normalize `y` before calling `wavwrite`

```
y_float = double(y)/2^15; %% Normalize int16(y) by 2^15
wavwrite(y_float,Fs, 't1.wav');
```

In the case that something goes wrong with `wavplay` reading the floating point `y_float`, you can convert the read-back signal from floating point to int16 again:

```
y_float_readback = wavread('t1.wav');
y_int16_readback = int16(y_float_readback*2^15);
wavplay(y_int16_readback);
```

You may compare `y_int16_readback` with the original `y`. They should be identical.

Answer (score 0):

This script works absolutely fine for me using the latest version of matlab. I heard clear audio using both your 1st and 2nd code excerpts.

One thing I noticed is that you record y as 'int16' type and then save it to the wav file. When you load the wav file using wavread, y is stored in the matlab workspace as double precision floating point data by default. If you want y to be loaded in the same format in which you saved it try the following.

```
y=wavread('t1.wav','native');
wavplay(y);
```